# Why is my doubly linked list not adding elements to the list

Tags: java, stack, doubly-linked-list

I am supposed to write a code that pushed nodes to the doubly linked stack, except I have to have the first added element (top) at the end of the stack, meaning the last added element should be the first one in the doubly linked list.

Here's my code for the push method

```
public void push(T dataItem) {
    
    DoubleLinkedNode<T> newNode = new DoubleLinkedNode<T>(dataItem);
    
    if(top == null) {
        
        top = newNode;
        
    }
    
    else {
         
        DoubleLinkedNode<T> currentNode = top;
        
        while (currentNode.getPrevious() != null){
            
            currentNode = currentNode.getPrevious();
            
        }
        
        newNode.setNext(currentNode);
        currentNode.setPrevious(newNode);
        
    }
    
    numItems++;
    
}
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? Is it not working? Maybe you can show us the class for the DoubleLinkedNode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.